Editing my answer to include content from another
I answered this question but another answer expands on something I said and is much clearer on that point. Overall I think my answer is better but could do with a bit more detail - is it acceptable to copy the content from the other answer or rewrite it in my own words and add it to my answer?
I've upvoted the other answer and will give credit but not sure about the etiquette here.


Overall I think my answer is better but could do with a bit more detail

Then feel free to include more details or enhance on it :)

is it acceptable to copy the content from the other answer [...]

No.

[...] or rewrite it in my own words and add it to my answer?

If you did this, then you will not be adding anything new to the post (you'll basically be restating what others said). Furthermore, you'll be making your answer a bit of a copycat of this other answer, making it less unique and decreasing its value/impact.
In general terms we have the "Back it up and Don't Repeat Others" guideline, which basically asks us to try to back up our answers (either with facts or experience) and avoid repeating/restating others.
... so I'd say no, don't rewrite it in your own words and add it to your answer.

My suggestion is that if you enhance your answer, do it independently of what this other answer says.
Of course, sometimes reading another answer can inspire us or remind us of something we perhaps missed, and that can lead to wanting to enhance the answer. That's perfectly fine as long as such enhancement does not conflict the don't repeat others rule.
Personally, I've even deleted answers that I just posted when I see one or more other answers that cover all I said and more (as to avoid just echoing others).
As an extreme (an silly?) example to see why all this. Imagine going to a question, studying all posted answers, and writing another one that basically fuses all the other answers and rephrases them... will this add value to the post and the user? Nope... should we expect that all other answers are deleted as now our answer includes all that and more? Nope...
Another thing I sometimes do. When I see that an answer is basically what I would have posted but lacks a good phrasing I go ahead and (1) suggest clarification to OP in a comment asking to rephrase, (2) given my reputation (ignoring mod status) I could go ahead and just edit the question and make it more clear (I see you have passed the 2000+ rep threshold for that).
If such answer is basically what I've said but lacks some minor things, you could comment in the answer asking OP to clarify/enhance on such thing or details (i.e.: "good answer. What would you suggest OP to do if X situation happens? mind enhancing on that?").
If I see no one enhances on such point, then another valid thing would be to post an answer that covers that specific point or situation. In this case is is more acceptable to mention (quoting/citing hmm not so much imo) the answers that are almost complete, and then proceed to give the points you feel are missing. For example:

I completely agree with the answer GrayCygnus provided. {insert null or VERY brief restatement of what you agree with the mentioned answer}.  However, I'd like to add that X situation could happen and if it does, the OP should do Y and Z.


*Imagine going to a question, studying all posted answers, and writing another one that basically fuses all the other answers and rephrases them... will this add value to the post and the user? *
Possibly if it brings the various suggestions together in a coherent way!

@deep64blue and that's what I mean by you would only be rephrasing existing content to a new answer. Edit/enhance/clarify the existing content instead, to avoid "repeating others"

@deep64blue checked your answer and the edit you did, I think it's ok that way. You clarify/enhance on a relevant point your answer already included, and also fulfill the "etiquette" of referring to the answer/poster that motivated you. You basically included one new sentence which is ok. Besides, it's the well-known and sound advice on "your cv should be tailored to the role" :)... heres a link on the oldest reference I could find on tailoring resumes.
